# EasyPHP root password

Tags: phpmyadmin

This question has been posted several times, and the solution worked for other members but not for me.
I'm using easyphp 5.3.9
PhpMyAdmin 3.4.9
running on windows server under virtualbox.
i have set a password to root account, any sql request is runing fine with the website, but i can not access any more the MySql Admin page, i have the error :

## 1045 - - Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO)

i edited the config.inc.php file as you advised in other topics but without success:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; //tried localhost, same issue!
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'azerty';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; //tried false, no change
```

Comment: try it and let me know if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'azerty';
```

to

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```